# Reducing an approximation claim from a prime ideal to a maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> **Theorem**. Let $R$ be a domain, $K$ its fraction field and $L$ a field extension of $K$. Let $S$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $L$. Let $P_1,...,P_k$ be prime ideals in $S$ with $P_i \cap R = p$. Then there is always a solution $x$ to systems of the form $x \equiv x_i \bmod P_i$.

For a maximal ideal I see how CRT solves this.
The lecture notes claim that we may assume $p$ is maximal by localizing at $p$. How is this reduction done?

1. Is it clear that $P_i$ stay distinct upon localizing at $M =R \setminus p$?
2. Given target $x_i$, how do we raise some solution $x_p \in S_M$ for $x_p - y_i \in M^{-1}P_i$ to a solution in $S$?
3. The notes mention an isomorphism $S/pS \cong S_M/pS_M$. Is it relevant?

Comment: Could you give us a link to your notes? I believe that 3. is wrong, and I'd like to check if this is written correctly.

Comment: Sure, here are the notes, it is lemma 3.6: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p-kMy2VMCCohBiLZ8R5yi9-iLS4-hwSG/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Thank you for the link. As I noticed from the very beginning the isomorphism $S/\mathfrak pS \cong S_M/\mathfrak pS_M$ is wrong (consider the case $\mathfrak p=(0)$), and their observation that every element in $R\setminus\mathfrak p$ is invertible in $R/\mathfrak p$ is also wrong.